# Writing Update Statement Derby

Tags: sql, derby

How do I update a value that is referencing a foreign key.

Lets say if I wanted to change a members email and email in the members table referenced Persons email. Since I cant do Update Cascade, how do I go about doing this in derby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each SQL update statement updates a single table. To update multiple tables, you must issue multiple update statements. You can gather these update statements into a single transaction, which ensures that other users of the database are never aware of a partially-updated database (they always see either all the updates, or none of them). Derby implements very standard SQL behaviors in this respect, so any common SQL reference can be consulted for understanding Derby's behavior.